# Possible to have multiple sizes of custom selectboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I've been searching for a good way in which to style up a selectbox, and have found a couple of good jQuery plugins that do the trick... However, they replace the selectbox with an input and a list and then give it a specific class which is used to add your custom styling...

This is fine and dandy, but I need to be able to use multiple sizes. The script is adding the same class to all of the replaced elements, so there's no way that I can find to style them with different widths.

Here's the script I'm talking about: http://www.brainfault.com/2008/02/10/new-release-of-jquery-selectbox-replacement

I just need to be able to have two distinct sizes/widths of the custom selectboxes. One for numbers such as 1-1000, and another for longer textual names such as "Transylvania County Home Buyers Association".

Obviously, one size would look ridiculous if I used the larger size to hold a list of numbers that only goes to 1000, and visa versa.

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That plugin lets you supply classes via its setup options; can't you just give it whatever classes you need to distinguish big ones from little ones?

Here's the page: http://www.brainfault.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-selectbox-replacement/

Comment: wow, I feel like a total goob now... Not sure what I was thinking when I saw where it defines the classes, but I was apparently not reading it correctly.

Thanks for pointing it out, and sorry to waste your time! haha